# Import a github project to Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, github

I'm getting started with the Google Earth Engine (GEE). As far as I gathered, GEE uses git-repositories (which are listed [here](https://earthengine.googlesource.com/?format=HTML)) to store my GEE files, so it seems a git-workflow should be possible.

From my predecessor I already have github-repositories containing GEE files, so I'm wondering now: Is it possible to "import" an existing github-repository to GEE (so I don't have to "copy" files from the existing repository)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import from github.  You will have to essentially copy.   (see: https://alexlvovich.com/blog/copy-git-repository-with-branches-to-another)